# Call function on map marker click - Google Map V3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I try to add a function on every map marker click. So every map marker click do another function. Here is my function:

```
function test1() {  
  jQuery('#Nav1').toggle();
}
function test2() {  
  jQuery('#Nav2').toggle();
}
```

Here are my markers:

```
var markers = [
  { lat: 43.963395, lng: 15.419338, name: "Marker1", icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png', funkcija: "test1" },
  { lat: 45.001831, lng: 14.89686, name: "Marker2", icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png', funkcija: "test2" }
];
```

And here is my function to create markers:

```
for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);
function addMarker(data) {
  // Create the marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
    map: map,
    title: data.name,
    icon: data.icon

  });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
     // do the function
});
```

I try with this but nothing.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   data.funkcija()
});
```

If I manualy enter function then it works but same fonction for all markers

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   test1()
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is rely on the functions being part of the windows scope, and refer to them dynamically like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   window[data.funkcija]();
});
```

See http://derek.io/blog/2009/dynamic-function-names-in-javascript/